# Smallest number whose residues are all different when divided by first $n$ primes

Tags: nt.number-theory

For each positive integer $n$, let $A(n)$ be the least number such that the n residues resulting from dividing $A(n)$ by the first $n$ primes are all different.

How accurate an estimate can one find for $A(n)$?

Comment: Sequence [A279073](https://oeis.org/A279073) in the OEIS.

Comment: An easy upper bound is $n^{cn}$, by restating Wikipedia’s estimate for the $n$th primorial (product of the first $n$ primes). This is because when $p_n\#-1$ is divided by $p_i$, the remainder is $p_i-1$, and all those remainders are distinct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial#Definition_for_prime_numbers

Comment: @MattF. In fact the $n$th primorial is $n^{n+o(n)}$, and this is the statement in the Wikipedia page you linked.